# Searching for files & moving

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am searching for all files ending with `.mkv`.  These are all in separate directories.

When I find a file, I want to move the parent directory to another folder.

```
for video in Path('/home/public/video/finished/').rglob('*.mkv'):
    shutil.move(str(video.parent), '/home/public/video/delete/')
```

This works, but if there are several directories that need to be moved, only one is moved and I'm getting an error:

```
  File "./py-test.py", line 13, in <module>
    for video in Path('/home/public/video/finished/').rglob('*.mkv'):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 1112, in rglob
    for p in selector.select_from(self):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 559, in _select_from
    for starting_point in self._iterate_directories(parent_path, is_dir, scandir):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 549, in _iterate_directories
    for p in self._iterate_directories(path, is_dir, scandir):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 545, in _iterate_directories
    entries = list(scandir(parent_path))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/pathlib.py", line 387, in wrapped
    return strfunc(str(pathobj), *args)
```

I tried `os.rename()` but it complains about the source directory not being empty.

Comment: I guess you first need to create a list of the directories you want to be moved because you are interacting with them in the ```for``` loop. Once finished creating the list, just go ahead and move the directories. And since you are using ```pathlib```, there is no reason to use ```shutils``` nor ```os``` modules.

Comment: Your code is referring to move the file. Can you share the code where you are trying to move the folder?

Comment: @roshanok, it is there: ```shutil.move(str(video.parent), '/home/public/video/delete/')```. Since ```video``` is a ```pathlib.Path``` object ```video.parent``` refers to the directory where the file is in.

Comment: thank @accdias. You are right. And you are right with the explanation too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
from pathlib import Path

source_dir = Path('/home/public/video/finished')
target_dir = Path('/home/public/video/delete')

dirs_to_move = []

for obj in source_dir.glob('*'):
    if obj.is_dir() and next(obj.rglob('*.mkv'), None):
        if obj not in dirs_to_move:
            dirs_to_move.append(obj)

if dirs_to_move:
    for dir in dirs_to_move:
        dir.rename(target_dir/dir.name)
```

Bear in mind that if you have `/home/public/video/finished/dir/subdir/file.mkv`, the code above will move `/home/public/video/finished/dir` to the `target_dir`.

It is **untested** though. Handle with care! :-)

Here is a small proof of concept but not moving anything. Just listing directories containing `.jpg` files:

```
Python 3.7.5 (default, Oct 17 2019, 12:16:48) 
[GCC 9.2.1 20190827 (Red Hat 9.2.1-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from pathlib import Path
>>> home = Path('/home/accdias')
>>> for obj in home.glob('*'):
...     if obj.is_dir() and next(obj.rglob('*.jpg'), None):
...             print(obj)
... 
/home/accdias/Downloads
/home/accdias/Dropbox
/home/accdias/Pictures
/home/accdias/git
/home/accdias/.local
/home/accdias/Wallpapers
>>>
```

Comment: You can change `len(list(obj.rglob('*.mkv')))` to just `list(obj.rglob('*.mkv'))` since `list`s are truthy when non-empty anyway. Or change it to `next(obj.rglob('*.mkv'), False)` to avoid running out the iterator when you're just need to check if any such files exist.

Comment: @ShadowRanger, indeed. Thanks. I guess ```next()``` will be more efficient than ```list()```ing everything.

Comment: Thanks accdias, but I am not moving all directories with mkv file just some.  I'm testing with a short script, my main script is doing much more testing of how long files are sitting in my finished directory. 

It seems I can not do a find for mkv files with glob & get the parent directory and do a move also.

Comment: @RobF., no worries. I hope that helps you as a starting point.